# How to make sure communication is stable when using a ZeroMQ REQ-REP in NodeJs-Golang

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, zeromq

This is my Node code

```
async function runClient() {
    console.log('Connecting to hello world server…');

    //  Socket to talk to server
    const sock = new zmq.Request();
    sock.connect('tcp://localhost:5555');
    let i = 0;

    while (true) {
        const msgToSend = 'Hello';
        console.log(`Count: ${i} Sending: ${msgToSend}`);

        await sock.send(msgToSend);

        const [result] = await sock.receive();
        console.log(`Count: ${i} Received: ${result.toString()}`);

        i++;
    }
}
```

and here's my Golang

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
)

func main() {
    responder, _ := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.REP)
    defer responder.Close()
    responder.Bind("tcp://*:5555")

    for {
        // Wait for next request from client
        msg, _ := responder.Recv(0)
        log.Printf("Received %sr\n", msg)

        // Do some 'work'
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

        // Send reply back to client
        responder.Send("World", 0)
    }
}
```

They are both connected and have outputs to the console but sometimes, the server (Golang) just stops at either `responder.Recv(0)` or `responder.Send("World", 0)`, with an error like this,

```
fatal error: schedule: in cgo

runtime stack:
runtime_mstart
        ../../../src/libgo/runtime/proc.c:596

goroutine 1 [runnable]:
github.com/pebbe/zmq4._C2func_zmq4_msg_recv
        /tmp/go-build/b003/_cgo_gotypes.go:372
github.com/pebbe/zmq4.Socket.RecvBytes..func1
        /home/uneex/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pebbe/zmq4@v1.2.10/zmq4.go:1082
github_0com_1pebbe_1zmq4.Socket.RecvBytes
        /home/uneex/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pebbe/zmq4@v1.2.10/zmq4.go:1082
github_0com_1pebbe_1zmq4.Socket.Recv
        /home/uneex/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pebbe/zmq4@v1.2.10/zmq4.go:1062
main.main
        /mnt/c/Users/golang-user/zmq/main.go:148
exit status 2
```

```
/mnt/c/Users/golang-user/zmq/main.go:148
```

`main.go:148` in the error points to `responder.Recv(0)`, but sometimes it could be `main.go:155`, which would be `responder.Send("World", 0)`

from the ZMQ Guide, it is said that

> In C and some other languages, strings are terminated with a null
> byte. We could send a string like “HELLO” with that extra null byte:
>
> zmq_send (requester, "Hello", 6, 0);
>
> However, if you send a string from another language, it probably will
> not include that null byte

but i don't actually know how to even begin to format the strings from Go to JavaScript, any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are, despite appearances, notably implementation dependent. Try putting in some special characters and you soon learn the differences between languages and how differently they can encode strings. As the comment from ZeroMQ's manual says, C does one thing, other languages do another.

ZeroMQ itself is merely a transporter of bytes, it does not translate language specific types for you, though some languages may convert strings to bytes in some manner or other.

The best bet is to use a heterogeneous serialiser, such as Google Protocol Buffers (which supports both Go and JavaScript), and get ZeroMQ to transport the serialised messages. This might sound like overkill for mere strings, but it would at least guarantee that, no matter what languages are used, you won't run into problems. Also, having crossed that Rubicon, you're then able to mix in more complex types / message structures easily.